# Exporting python selenium file with other files into .exe file (Solved)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller

I am trying to export a python selenium file with other .csv files and .txt files and the chromedriver.exe into a .exe file.

I have tried using auto py to exe and pyinstaller to export into an .exe file but when I try to run the .exe file it doesn't work. Turning on debug shows it destroying and cleaning up libraries, but nothing after that. The file works fine with .py.

So what I did was:

1. Store all my files into a directory
2. Used auto py to exe (GUI
   pyinstaller) to add files, and --onefile options and --debug for all
3. Exe file generated shows a bunch of libraries being destroyed and cleaned up, nothing after that, no error message
4. Tried with --onedir and --onefile but both would not work

Questions:

Why does my .exe file compiled result in no error messages? Is there some other options for pyinstaller I should be using? Is there some lines of code I should be adding? My code has print statements but nothing is being printed.

What might be the best configuration when trying to export selenium python files with the chrome driver? Would it be better to have it as onefile or onedir?

Thanks in advance!

Apparently there was a module that was not imported properly, causing an error where the module could not be found. The fix would be to add --hidden-import pkg_resources.py2_warn to the py installer command. E.g. pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import pkg_resources.py2_warn "file.py"

Comment: This is a bit confusing - can you edit with a step by step guide to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Please add more details to your question.

Comment: I edited my question, hope its more clear now.